# Angular Typeahead not matching on lost focus

Tags: angularjs, typeahead

I am using the Angular Typeahead (ui.bootstrap.typeahead) with a static array  of objects (eah with a name and id attribute).

I am using the "*select* as *label* for *value* in *sourceArray*" format so as to ultimately retrieve the selected id (rather than the name)

When the *exact* text as one of the array name elements is entered **and** the input loses focus by **clicking** out (this is not a problem if you tab out) the typeahead does not match to the element id...

example plunker to demonstrate the problem here : http://plnkr.co/edit/E1NEaSVinXdUOUO6nHSZ?p=preview

Comment: Yes, this is by design - it is the same behaviour as in the original Bootstrap (http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#typeahead), on which this directive is based (behaviour-wise)

Comment: OK, accepted. But surely it's a valid that *some* users will fill in forms by clicking from one field to the next (no tabbing) and would expect to be able to type in the correct value without having to select it from the typeahead ???